# The difference between installation apk on Eclipse and on mobile?

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, apk

I start a no icon Activity. I use the below code：

```
public class AndroidTestNoiconActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
}
```

I connect my computer with mobile using USB.

Method 1: Installation apk on mobile through `Eclipse-->Run-->Run Configurations`

Effect:  Application icon hidden

Method 2: Copy apk to sdcard directly and install use mobile.

Effect:  Application icon did not be hidden.

What is difference between installation apk on Eclipse and on mobile?

Comment: Have you try to run app after installing from sdcard? I suppose this method should work, but only after first app start.